trying to install a package in an "airflow" context, but module can't be found (ModuleNotFoundError)
I have used docker desktop to install airflow. And I have copied some sample dags available on localhost to my vscode environment and that code works fine. But when I tried to apply my python code that has module cv2 imported , the dag was broken. Module is not found appeared in the log. When I check with
pip show

, the module showed up. I know some modules like pyautogui (interactive type of module) won't work with airflow. But I am not sure if this is the same case as cv2 module.
The result of
pip show opencv-python-headless 

is:
WARNING: Package(s) not found: opencv-python-headless

Also for pip list to have all modules installed,
opencv-python version 4.10.0.84

I am very new to airflow, let me know if any clarification needed.


Have any chance to add result of pip list | grep cv2 and pip show opencv-python-headless this result on your question. Also could you add raw format of your error in an eligible format for making easier to read it?

you entered grep in a windows terminal. you need to understand your environment first.

@maxemilian thx, I have updated my question

@ChristophRackwitz Sorry for the confusion, I updated just now

airflow issue. OpenCV people can't help with that. learn to determine which python environment you're working in. if you installed something, you probably installed it in another python environment than the one you need it in.

@ChristophRackwitz Other installations do not break the dag. So it is not related to the python environment.
